# What is the REST call I need to make to the TeamCity API to get this build status below? The one I'm using is not correct

Tags: powershell, api, teamcity

[image]

I've been scouring for the answer to this for the last several days.  There's many fields labeled "status" in the TC API and for the life of me, I can't figure out which one returns the status listed above.

I'm currently calling...

$status = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri %teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:%teamcity.build.id% -Method Get -Headers $header).build.status

...within PowerShell.  This returns SUCCESS unless the build has an execution timeout.  However, as you can see from the screenshot above, the build failed.  Obviously, the call above doesn't return the right status.  The failure is due to a specific build step failing.  If any of the build steps fail, then the entire build fails.  Not sure if that helps!

Comment: Just a suggestion. Don't confuse *Build number* with *Build id*.

Maybe you can ask something else to be sure that your are locating the right "build execution".

Comment: Per looking at the Network tab of Chrome while loading the TC page, the build ID variable that's being passed in is correct and matches the latest build number.  The problem is trying to find the right field in returned JSON from the API call.  The build.status field seems like the obvious choice, but apparently isn't.  I find it odd that it shows "Failure" when there is an execution timeout, but not when the status is "Failure".  I'm thinking I need to maybe do something with the locators, like "?locator=defaultFilter:false", or something like that?  I can't be the only one trying to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is what was happening.  I have an build step in TeamCity that runs Katalon (our test automation software).  Even though the tests were failing, TeamCity was not updating the build status until after the last step, which happened to be my PS script that called the API then sent the info over to MS Teams.  I had to setup a Failure Condition in TeamCity for the Katalon build step that looks in the build log for the specific text "(Katalon) failed".  This immediately fails the build, but the rest of the build steps continue to run.  Now, when my last step runs, it pulls the correct status and pushes it to MS Teams.  For anyone that is interested, this is the full PowerShell script for that build step.

```
    function Get-AuthenticationHeader
{
param($User, $Password)
$pair = "$($User):$($Password)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
"Basic $encodedCreds"
}

$authHeader = Get-AuthenticationHeader -User "%system.teamcity.auth.userId%" -Password "%system.teamcity.auth.password%"

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$header = @{
    "Authorization"="$authHeader"
}

$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -Uri "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/%teamcity.build.id%")

$status = $response.build.status
$name = "%system.teamcity.buildConfName%"
$teamcityAgent = "%teamcity.agent.name%"
$testResults = $response.build.webUrl

Write-Host "%teamcity.build.id%"
Write-Host $status
Write-Host $name
Write-Host $testResults

if ( $status -eq "SUCCESS" ) {
    $color = "00ff00"
}
else {
    $status = "FAILURE"
    $color = "ff0000"
}

$body = @{
    title= "API Test Automation";
    text= "<pre><b><i><font color=$color>$status</font></i></b> - $name<br>Tests ran on <i>$teamcityAgent</i><br>Test results are <a href=""$testResults"">HERE</a></pre>"
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Uri "<YOUR MS TEAMS WEBHOOK HERE>" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be in the endpoint itself. You are requesting the correct field. The same can also be done with the following requests:

```
GET /app/rest/builds?locator=id:%teamcity.build.id%&fields=build(status)
GET /app/rest/builds/%teamcity.build.id%/status
```

The first request will return you an XML or JSON structure depending on your `Accept` header. The second response will return you plain text, so set the headers accordingly.

> This returns SUCCESS unless the build has an execution timeout. However, as you can see from the screenshot above, the build failed. Obviously, the call above doesn't return the right status. The failure is due to a specific build step failing. If any of the build steps fail, then the entire build fails.

You are requesting the build status during the build execution. It is possible, that when the build step that checks the status is running, the status of the build is still SUCCESS. Try moving the build step to the very end of this build and configure it to execute 'Always, even if build stop command was issued'

Comment: Well, I already have it as the last build step, and I already had the "Always, even if" option selected for the build step.  Going back to your comment about maybe the status hasn't changed yet...I'm going to try putting a delay in the PowerShell, something along the lines of 15-30 seconds.  There is a short cleanup PS script between the test step and the MS Teams notification PS script.  I'll post back with results once I try it.

Comment: Ok, I kind of figured it out.  I put a 30 second sleep in the beginning of the MS Teams PS script.  The status still returns as SUCCESS.  However, if I then call the same build id after the MS Teams build step runs, then I get FAILURE.  It appears that TeamCity does not update build status until after all build steps are complete, even if one of the earlier ones fails.  Is there any way to force TeamCity to fail the build immediately upon a build step failing?  Otherwise, this method of trying to get the build status and publish it to MS Teams when the project runs is not going to work, ever!